# 500 Internal Server Error php code ec2 instance

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, http-post, internal-server-error

I have a PHP file with a post API call (refer below).

```
<html>

<head>
    <Title>Temp</Title>
    <link rel="icon" href="logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <script>
        <?php
        // $tranData = "hello world";
        $tranData = $_REQUEST['trandata'];
        $status = 'ERROR_PAGE';
        // $tranData = '22120070AE5D3475A66502266511A34F5691A46962B2A83C34C93C45A43DA9D7335946B521A60E588312EBFCF60791C100F4990A09CA527936FC9B0F39552848BB7B119269A665080A20EA66ECD2802D64ACBEC4B6A9A57AC34A73EF0A81FD9A27878DCFE5A545A56FDFA34D82879B8DE833989E2125ED011D4CCE78C3698D8C83D2F4616C0D9461167BA97DC4788B5E4D8B2B142B6DAAAC639699C1C25221022C05D08C9ACD90A129E2CB5CFA7F40CE60BA3758AFCA0AED1E47FD2CDAA07B248D5AB14E2C08AD4BD27471C77957D663ED6B7F562E8F0FD1B845D051B2DC9A51';
        if ($tranData != '') {
            $data = array(
                'action' => 'decrypt',
                'type' => 'knet',
                'trandata' => $tranData
            );
            $url = '<api_url>'; 
            $ch = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
                CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json'),
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data)
            ));
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            if ($response === FALSE) {
                die(curl_error($ch));
            }
            $responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);
            $responses;
            $paymentId;
            if ($responseData['statusCode'] == 200) {
                $responses = explode("&", $responseData['decrypt_trandata']);
                $paymentId = explode("=", $responses[0])[1];
                $status = explode("=", $responses[1])[1];
            } else {
                $status = 'decryption error';
            }
        } else {
            $status = 'ERROR PAGE';
        }
        ?>
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='normalView' class="successView">Hello World <?php echo ($status);
                                                            echo ($paymentId); ?></div>
</body>

</html>
```

In the localhost, it is working as expected.

Now I have uploaded this file to my ec2 instance. When I opened the page with ec2 url, the following error appeared,

[image]

If I removed the POST API call code, the page is rendering fine. Normal PHP variables also working as expected.

I'm sure there is some problem while doing this API call in ec2 instance.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Check the webservers error log to see what the actual error message is.

Comment: Hey Eriksson! Thanks man. As I am new to this env, I didn't aware of the error.log file. I got it now. It is the problem with curl. php curl has not installed. Cheers!